# Was there ever a name for the weapons of the Others?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

When I think of weapons made of ice, I usually think of Stahlrim weapons from *Skyrim*, do the ice weapons from the show have a name? What about the books?

Answer (score 18):

It's hard to prove a negative but as far as I am aware no formal name is ever given to the ice weapons. When asked what they are made out of George R. R. Martin answered the below, if he was ever going to formally name them that would seem like the perfect opportunity.

> **Shaw:** Do you know what substance an Other sword is made from.
>
> **Martin:** Ice. But not like regular old ice. The Others can do things with ice that we can't imagine and make substances of it.
>
> <sub>[George R. R. Martin interview with Robert Shaw (archived)](http://web.archive.org/web/20051103091500/nrctc.edu/fhq/vol1iss3/00103009.htm/)</sub>

As @Aegon has mentioned in a comment we do see the Others communicating in the Prologue for *A Game of Thrones* so it's likely that they themselves have a name for their weapons. It's just that those in universe can't understand it and so the name is never passed on to the reader.

> The Other said something in a language that Will did not know; his voice was like the cracking of ice on a winter lake, and the words were mocking.
>
> <sub>*A Game of Thrones*, Prologue</sub>

Lastly, it is worth noting that the Others are deliberately shrouded in mystery and so small details like that are not going to be revealed especially when larger details haven't been.

Comment: I'll probably name them stahlrim from now on XD, I'd say it's quite similar to their ice

Comment: @Termatinator It is very likely that they do have a name for their weapons. We saw them communicating with each other in AGOT I. If they have a language, it stands to reason they must have a word for their weapons as well. It just hasn't been revealed yet because the Others are still shrouded in mystery.

Comment: Ice, but like, *magical* ice...